# Solver synchronous termination not working after update

Tags: optaplanner

After updating Optaplanner from version 6.0.1 to 6.1.0, I noticed that the solver does not stop when using the synchronous termination.

For instance, both of the following configurations do not work anymore:

```
 <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>5</secondsSpentLimit>
  </termination>
```

AND

```
<termination>
      <bestScoreLimit>-1000/0/0</bestScoreLimit>
  </termination>
```

Most strange of all, when using a wrong value for the synchronous termination like the follwing :

```
 <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>-5</secondsSpentLimit>
  </termination>
```

It does not lead to any error!
So it looks like the solver does not care anymore about the synchronous termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fail-fast check that `secondsSpentLimit` is not negative in 6.1.0.Final. But it's a good idea, so [I just added it for 6.2.0.Beta3](http://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/commit/46cb26e92).

I have seen the solver stop on synchronous termination in 6.1.0, so **presuming `daemonMode` is false** (which it is by default), there must be something special in your case. Confirm that `deamonMode` is not specified (or it is `false`) in your case, submit a jira (see optaplanner.org -> code > create an issue) and attach a reproducer zip.

Also double check if your terminations are inside `<solver>` or in a `<phase>`. If it's in a phase (instead of the solver) and it's not the last phase, it won't stop the solver.

Comment: The daemonMode is not specified in my case cause i'm not using real time planning. The termination is of course inside the <solver>. On the other hand, the termination of the last phase does stop the phase but does not return from solve() so it looks like the solver is just waiting for nothing until i call terminateEarly(). As for Jira, unfortunately, i'm not allowed to submit the whole code of my project.

Comment: Do you have any other clues of where to look for the fix ?

Comment: I just need an isolated reproducer (not the entire project). If I can't reproduce it, I can't fix it... Anyway, put a breakpoint in `TimeMillisSpentTermination.isTerminated()`. Also put a breakpoint in `LocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep()` and `DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve()`'s use of termination (note that will be a `BasicPlumbingTermination` which wraps the `TimeMillisSpentTermination`. If you find out what it is, do report it here (no matter what the cause).

Comment: I resolved my problem. It was due to this line in my code : solverFactory.getSolverConfig().setDaemon(true); I think i did copy it from an example without paying attention. Thank you for you help Geoffrey :)